# What is the Non UI role in crash reports

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crash-dumps, darwin, xnu

When analysing crash reports, I'm seeing a `Non UI` role that I have never seen before. I am trying to understand what state of the app it corresponds to.

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4 (15F79)
Report Version:      104
```

The `Role` header is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-CRASH_HEADER), which points to the kernel source. In the [latest available version](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.41.2/osfmk/mach/task_policy.h.auto.html) of the source (as well as previous versions), I see a `TASK_NONUI_APPLICATION` enum constant, but it is undocumented.

There is already a `TASK_FOREGROUND_APPLICATION` and a `TASK_BACKGROUND_APPLICATION` constant, so I don't understand what `Non UI` (or `TASK_NONUI_APPLICATION`) can be.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it was launched by a a background mode?  Does your app support one of the following [background modes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-background-execution-modes#Specify-the-background-modes-your-app-requires)?  iOS *can* fully launch an app into the background if it receives an event like a location [notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/handling_location_updates_in_the_background#4061644) (emphasis mine):

> The system can terminate apps at any time to free up memory or other system resources. The system **relaunches** a terminated app only if the app has Always authorization and if it was running the significant change, visits, or region monitoring location service at the time of its termination.